# How to convert dumbo sequence file input to tab separated text

Tags: python, text, hadoop

I have in input, which could be a single primitive or a list or tuple of primitives.

I'd like to flatten it to just a list, like so:

```
def flatten(values):
    return list(values)
```

The normal case would be flatten(someiterablethatisn'tastring)

But if values = '1234', I'd get ['1', '2', '3', '4'], but I'd want ['1234']

And if values = 1, I'd get TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, but I'd want [1]

Is there an elegant way to do this?
What I really want to do in the end is just '\t'.join(flatten(values))

Edit: Let me explain this better...

I wish to convert a hadoop binary sequence file to a flat tab separated text file using dumbo. Using the output format option, -outputformat text

Dumbo is a python wrapper around hadoop streaming. In short I need to write mapper function:

def mapper(key, values)
    #do some stuff
    yield k, v

where k is a string from the first part in the key, and value is a tab separated string containing the rest of the key and the values as strings.

eg:

```
input: (123, [1,2,3])
output: ('123', '1\t2\t\t3')
```

or more complicated:

```
input: ([123, 'abc'], [1,2,3])
output: ('123', 'abc\t1\t2\t\t3')
```

The input key or value can be a primitive or a list/tuple of primitives
I'd like a "flatten" function that can deal with anything, and return a list of values.

For the out value, I'll do something like this
v = '\t'.join(list(str(s) for s in flatten(seq)))

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Usually the term `flatten` indicates that you want to flatten nested lists into a single list (e.g. `[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`).  What you're asking for appears to be slightly different.  And if you're ultimately going to be feeding it to `str.join`, you're going to need to turn each element into a string while you're at it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python plus some confusion of what's a list.  `1` is not a list and can't be flattened; first it it has to be made into a list.  A `str` already is a sequence, so please be more specific about what's supposed to happen.

Comment: I know 1 isn't a list. If anyone is curious, this is the input I have to deal with on a dumbo mapper. I'm writing short mapper that will use dumbo to convert any sequence file to tab separated text. Agreed flatten isn't the best name for it, can't think of anything better though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`itertools.chain()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).  You will need to special-case strings, though, since they are really just iterables of characters.

**Update**:

This is a much simpler problem if you do it as a recursive generator.  Try this:

```
def flatten(*seq):
    for item in seq:
        if isinstance(item, basestring):
            yield item
        else:
            try:
                it = iter(item)
            except TypeError:
                yield item
                it = None
            if it is not None:
                for obj in flatten(it):
                    yield obj
```

This returns an iterator instead of a list, but it's lazily evaluated, which is probably what you want anyway.  If you really need a list, just use `list(flatten(seq))` instead.

**Update 2**:

As others have pointed out, if what you really want is to pass this into `str.join()`, then you will need to convert all the elements to strings.  To do that, you can either replace `yield foo` with `yield str(foo)` throughout my example above, or just use code like the following:

```
"\t".join(str(o) for o in flatten(seq))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your restated question, this `mapper` function might do what you want:

```
def mapper(key, values):
    r"""Specification: do some stuff yield k, v where k is a string from the
    first part in the key, and value is a tab separated string containing the
    rest of the key and the values as strings.

    >>> mapper(123, [1,2,3])
    ('123', '1\t2\t3')

    >>> mapper([123, 'abc'], [1,2,3])
    ('123', 'abc\t1\t2\t3')
    """
    if not isinstance(key, list):
        key = [key]
    k, v = key[0], key[1:]
    v.extend(values)
    return str(k), '\t'.join(map(str, v))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

It looks like you'll probably want to change that `return` to a `yield`.  This also assumes that the input key will always be a single item or a list of items (not a list of lists) and that the input values will always be a list of items (again, not a list of lists).

Does that meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I must say that the stated requirements are odd, and I don't think *flatten* is the right name for this kind of operation. But if you're **really** sure that this is what you want, then this is what I can distil from your question:

```
>>> import itertools 
>>> def to_list_of_strings(input):
...      if isinstance(input, basestring):   # In Py3k: isinstance(input, str)
...          return [input]
...      try:
...          return itertools.chain(*map(to_list_of_strings, input))
...      except TypeError:
...          return [str(input)]
... 
>>> '\t'.join(to_list_of_strings(8))
'8'
>>> '\t'.join(to_list_of_strings((1, 2)))
'1\t2'
>>> '\t'.join(to_list_of_strings("test"))
'test'
>>> '\t'.join(to_list_of_strings(["test", "test2"]))
'test\ttest2'
>>> '\t'.join(to_list_of_strings(range(4)))
'0\t1\t2\t3'
>>> '\t'.join(to_list_of_strings([1, 2, (3, 4)]))
'1\t2\t3\t4'
```

Comment: This is close, but it will fail with `to_list_of_strings([1, 2, (3, 4)])` -- it should return `["1", "2", "3", "4"]` but instead returns `["1", "2", "(3, 4)"]`

Comment: @Daniel: I actually assumed that the OP didn't really want to flatten like that. I'll update the answer.