# Python : Not able to get the list of the options that have been added via 'add_option'?

Tags: python, python-2.x

My code portion looks like:

```
 parser.add_option("-h", "--help","-?",
                   action = "help",
                   help= """Print the help of the scipt"""
                 )
```

When I am trying to print the options available for the script, it returns an empty array.

```
  optlist = [x.get_opt_string() for x in parser._get_all_options()[1:]]
  print optlist
```

Printing optlist prints an empty array -> 
    [ ].

I need to print an array with all the available options. In this case, an array that stores values: -h, --help and -?

Comment: what type is your `parser` object?  `argparse` module provides automatically generated help and usage messages, so you don't need to add those -> http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html

Comment: I can't get your code to run with either `argparse` or `optparse` -- `argparse` doesn't have `add_option` and `optparse` dies with "conflicting option string(s)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2.6.5 optparse objects have undocumented attributes _short_opts and _long_opts. For a bumpy list

```
[x._short_opts + x._long_opts for x in parser._get_all_options()]
```

Using [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python) to flatten the list

```
sum([x._short_opts + x._long_opts for x in parser._get_all_options()],[])
```

Comment: attributes prepended with an underscore are dubious to use externally (they can change without notice, breaking your code)