# Stripping characters from tuples in a list

Tags: python, json, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples in this form (generated by a DB query):

```
[(280.73,), (281.359,), (280.630,)]
```

I would like to remove the () and commas to achieve something like this, making it more compatible to form into a JSON.

```
[280.73,281.359,280.630]
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [join list of lists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @Johnsyweb for the exact same question repeated thousand of times (flatten a list).

Comment: @JBernardo: I don't think that the OP realised that was the question (no disrespect intended).

Comment: @Johnsyweb That's because OP thinks that everything is a string... But I doubt he checked for other questions before asking

Comment: Yes, I did check other questions. I just started with Python, and I did see it as a string, which is why I was looking to strip out the characters.
I see the single tuple now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest is probably through list comprehension:

```
cleaned = [i[0] for i in [(280.73,), (281.359,), (280.630,)]]
```

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I was looking at the variable wrong. I just started writing in Python, still not used to tuples.

Answer (score 6):

Given a `list` of *single-element* `tuple`s (let's call it `l` (for `list`)). You want to flatten this into a list of elements.

A list comprehension, extracting the first element of each tuple will do the job:

```
>>> l = [(280.73,), (281.359,), (280.630,)]
>>> [t[0] for t in l]
[280.73000000000002, 281.35899999999998, 280.63]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

These examples will work with arbitrary elements number of tuples.

```
>>> l = [(280.73,), (281.359,), (280.630,)]
>>> [ v for b in l for v in b ]
[280.73, 281.359, 280.63]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain(*l))
[280.73, 281.359, 280.63]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative hack, you can do this as well:

```
>>> stuff = [(280.73,), (281.359,), (280.630,)]
>>> sum(stuff, ())
(280.73, 281.359, 280.63)
```

To convert it to a list, pass it into the `list` function:

```
>>> stuff = [(280.73,), (281.359,), (280.630,)]
>>> list(sum(stuff, ()))
[280.73, 281.359, 280.63]
```