# "".join(list) if list contains a nested list in python?

Tags: python

I know that `"".join(list)` converts the list to a string, but what if that list contains a nested list? When I try it returns a `TypeError` due to unexpected list type. I'm guessing it's possible with error handling, but so far my attempts have been fruitless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL So much rep, and no dup vote? Already out of votes for today?

Comment: This command is used to concatenate strings. If the objects in the list are not strings (like lists, in your example) you will have to try to convert them to strings like suggested below first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if the list is nested, simply [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) it beforehand:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
>>> ''.join(itertools.chain(*lst))
'abcd'
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like this:

```
''.join(''.join(inner) for inner in outer)
```

That should work, and won't have too much trouble if the outer list contains both Strings and Lists inside of it, `''.join(myString) -> myString`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try this snippet:

```
from collections import Iterable

ellipsis = type('',(),{'__str__' : lambda self:'...'})()

def flatten(collection,stack = None):
    if not stack: stack = set()
    if id(collection) in stack:
        yield ellipsis
        return
    for item in collection:
        if isinstance(item,Iterable):
            stack.add(id(collection))
            for subitem in flatten(item,stack):
                yield subitem
            stack.remove(id(collection))
        else: yield item

x = [1,2,[3,4,[5],[[6]],7]]
x.append(x)

>>> print(', '.join(map(str,flatten(x))))
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
```