# Merge different lists together in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am so called newbie in Python.
I have difficulties with lists.
I have a loop which take some info from textfile and goes through function. If textfiles lenght is 10 rows then output will be 10 separate lists, like that:
[0.45]
[0.87] 
...
and so on, for n+1 times(it depends how long textfile is).

How can I put them into single list, like [0.45, 0.87, ...]?
I experimented with different loops but nothing :(

I am previously thankfull :)
.. and sry about my bad english

Code:

```
from pyfann import libfann
import os
path="."
ext = ".net"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if file.lower().endswith(ext)]
for j in files:
 ann = libfann.neural_net()
 ann.create_from_file(j)
 print j
 f=open('nsltest1.dat','r')
 for i in f:
  x=i.strip()
  y=[float(i) for i in x.split()]
  z=ann.run(y)
  print z
```

Comment: Copy/pastle your code here, then we might be able to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append list to second list (concatenate lists)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists)

Answer (score 11):

If you have all of your lists stored in a list `a`,

```
# a = [[.45], [.87], ...]
import itertools
output = list(itertools.chain(*a))
```

What makes this answer better than the others is that it neatly joins an arbitrary number of lists together in one line, without a need for a `for` loop or anything like that.

Comment: That's the problem, I do not know how to join them to another list

Comment: Well, your code is a little convoluted to begin with, but what you could do is outside looping through the text you could instantiate a variable `listoflists = []` and then in the `for` loop add each list item to the list with `listoflists.append(...)` or `listoflists += <item>` or `listoflists.extend(...)` depending on what you're trying to do.  [This](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) might help.

Comment: sir, what is "*" means ?

Answer (score 4):

Addition operator `+` is what you might want.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
merged_list = list1 + list2
print(merged_list) #replace ( and ) with spaces if you're using python 2.x
```

Will output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 4):

You might want to have a look at the following questions:

- [How to append list to second list (concatenate lists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python)
- [Combining lists into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424219/combining-lists-into-one)
- [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

Basically, if you're reading your lines in a loop, you can do like

```
result = []
for line in file:
    newlist = some_function(line) # newlist contains the result list for the current line
    result = result + newlist
```

Comment: Thank you, it gives me screen full of lines but I try to it more suitable for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can just **add** them: `[1] + [2] = [1, 2]`.