# Change the name of the lists with a for loop

Tags: python

I have some lists:

```
list_line[0] = ['my name is A']
list_line[0] = ['my name is B']
list_line[0] = ['my name is C']
list_line[0] = ['my name is D']
```

And I make this work:

```
list_words_0 = list_line[0].split()
list_words_1 = list_line[1].split()
list_words_2 = list_line[2].split()
list_words_3 = list_line[3].split()

list_words = list_words_0 + list_words_1 + list_words_2 + list_words_3
print list_words
```

So with the above steps, i can do it with a for-loop:
for i in range(3):
   do something

but i don't know how to put i in variables: list_words_0, list_words_1, list_words_2 ...
Can you help me change the name of that lists with a for loop? thank you so much !

Comment: It's not *some* lists, you have a list containing one nested list

Comment: Please post **correct** code and consider telling us what you are trying to accomplish, because it is not clear at all from what you have posted.

Comment: hi @shaktimaan! Thanks for your answer. But i want to parse that lists into the lists like this: list_line[0] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'A'], list_line[1] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'B'], list_line[2] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'C'], list_line[4] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'D']. And that is particular lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  What you want to do is loop 0 to i (i being the max amount of `list_words_` variables you want), then create a string that goes `"list_words_" + str(i)`.  Then use the dictionary to keep track of these:

```
#assume you're inside the loop
example_dictionary["list_words_" + str(i)] = list_line[0];
```

**NOTE**:  Treat this as pseudo code.  It's kind of late so I may have small syntax errors.

However, your question is a ***bit*** unclear.  It may be that you want to combine multiple lists or arrays into one list or array.  There are many examples of this already on this site (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/merge-two-lists-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424219/combining-lists-into-one)).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your data is like this since you are trying to do a `split` later on:

```
list_line = ['my name is A', 
 'my name is B', 
 'my name is C', 
 'my name is D']
```

Your end goal (of concatenating all the lists of words) can be achieved by simply doing:

```
output_list = []
for alist in list_line:
    output_list.append(alist.split())
```

prints

```
 [['my', 'name', 'is', 'A'],
 ['my', 'name', 'is', 'B'],
 ['my', 'name', 'is', 'C'],
 ['my', 'name', 'is', 'D']]
```

Comment: hi @shaktimaan! Thanks for your answer. But i want to parse that lists into the lists like this: list_line[0] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'A'], list_line[1] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'B'], list_line[2] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'C'], list_line[4] = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'D']. And that is particular lists

Comment: @user3208948 Change `extend` to `append` to get that. Updated my answer