# Simpler code to combine multiple lists into one array? I actually wish "lists" are still "lists" in that array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424219/combining-lists-into-one) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python), but the solutions to those is that all lists are "united" with lack of "differentiation".

My Python code is like following:

```
y = np.empty([1,len(test)]) 
count = -1 
for feature in test :
    N = engine.neighbours(np.asarray(feature))
        if len(N) != 4096:
            print "error"
            continue        
        count = count + 1
    y [count] = engine.neighbours(np.asarray(feature))
```

I am just wondering if there is any simplified code to do the job?

Comment: sorry for the poor code writing, here is the actually screen printout -- http://screencloud.net/v/jhyA

Comment: Your question seems like it has nothing to do with the other questions. Those questions are about flattening lists into single lists. You don't seem to want that. Have you tried `append`?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  yes i tried, does not looks good, though i do not know why the outcome is none, i hope it is going to generate one array with two lists (elements) inside the array. http://screencloud.net/v/hxHT  , another example is here  http://screencloud.net/v/lRnA  thanks :)

Comment: You may want to correct the indentation of the code for making it readable. Just use spaces, and not tab.

Comment: Don't recommend `np.append`.  It is just a form of `concatenate`, and is often used erroneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked questions have to do with flattening a list of lists.  In your code you are processing a list of lists (I'm guessing), filtering out some, and collecting the rest in a 2d array.

Oops!  `y` is initialized with 1 row, yet you try to place values in `y[count]`, where `count` could increase to the size of `test`.

```
y = np.empty([1,len(test)]) 
count = -1    
# I would prefer to start with 0, but thats a style issue
for feature in test :
    N = engine.neighbours(np.asarray(feature))
    # so engine.neighbors requires an array; and returns an array?
        if len(N) != 4096:
            print "error"
            continue        
        count = count + 1
    y [count] = engine.neighbours(np.asarray(feature))
    # why call neighbors again?  why not reuse N?
```

A common way of creating an array incrementally is:

```
alist = []
for feature in tests:
     N = engine.neighbors(np.array(feature)
     # test N length
     alist.append(N)
y = np.array(alist)
```

Since by the length test, all `N` have the same length, the resulting array will be 2d, shape `(n,4096)`, where `n` is the number of tests with the correct length.

Initializing `y` to `np.empty((length(tests),4096)]`, and inserting `y[count,:] = N` may be faster.  You may end up with unfilled rows if some fail the length test, but you can remove those.

Initializing `y` to `np.empty((1,4096)]`, and inserting `y=np.append(y,N)` should also work.  Note that this `append` is different from the list append.  And slower.  I prefer that people use `concatenate` directly:

```
y = np.concatenate([y, N[None,:]], axis=0)
```

The concatenation is explicit, and the required dimension manipulation clear.

To make a 1d array of arrays, you have to do something like this:

```
y=np.empty((4,),dtype=object)
for i in range(len(y)):
    y[i]=np.arange(i,2*i)
```

producing:

```
array([array([], dtype=int32), array([1]), array([2, 3]), array([3, 4, 5])], dtype=object)
```

which is arguably little more than the `y` list produced by

```
y=[]
for i in range(4):
    y.append(np.arange(i,2*i))
```

In all this I'm assuming that `engine.neighbors()` takes a 1d array, and returns a 1d array.  If if took/returned multiple `feature` we could 'vectorize' things.  But as long as we can only give it one `feature` at a time we are stuck with some form of iteration.