# How to get flat list in list comprehension from lists of arbitrary number of elements?

Tags: python

I have something like this:

```
[e for e in ([n for n in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))] for x in xrange(10))]
```

It produces:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0], [0], [0, 1], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

And I need the same but in flat structure.

For now I use something like:

```
l = []
[l.extend(e) for e in ([n for n in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))] for x in xrange(10))]
```

But is there something less obsucre to achieve this 'unpacking' of arbitrary length list inside comprehension?

Comment: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to flatten any iterable in a generic situation is [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import random
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> x = [e for e in ([n for n in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))] 
...      for x in xrange(10))]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(x))
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2]
```

This said, it's preferable to avoid the extra work in this case by just [making it flat to begin with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15863005/722121).

Answer (score 7):

Use this list comprehension:

```
In [8]: [y for x in xrange(10) for y in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))]
Out[8]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

The above list comprehension is equivalent to this(but LC are much faster):

```
In [9]: lis=[]

In [10]: for x in xrange(10):
   ....:     for y in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5)):
   ....:         lis.append(y)
   ....:
```

Comment: +1 - The best option here is to make it the way you want, not flatten it after.

Comment: +1 I didn't know whe could nest for loops into list comprehension

Comment: xrange and random is just for illustration! My case requires that elems that pops from data srouce is arbitrary length lists

Comment: @GillBates `for y in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))` iterates over that arbitrary lenght list to return a flattened list.

Comment: Iterates and generates it, in my case of course Im not generating data inside list comprehension

Answer (score 3):

You can use [numpy flatten()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
import numpy as np
l = [e for e in ([n for n in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))] for x in xrange(10))]
a = np.asarray(l)
l = list(a.flatten(l))
print l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
l = [e for e in ([n for n in xrange(random.randrange(1, 5))] for x in xrange(10))]
result = list(itertools.chain(*l))
```

and then `print result` gives:

```
[0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0...]
```

the use of the `*` in chain(*l) is inspired from this question [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python) .

Comment: This is slower than `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` that was designed to do this more efficiently.