# python .count for multidimensional arrays (list of lists)

Tags: python

How would I count the number of occurrences of some value in a multidimensional array made with nested lists? as in, when looking for 'foobar' in the following list:

```
list = [['foobar', 'a', 'b'], ['x', 'c'], ['y', 'd', 'e', 'foobar'], ['z', 'f']]
```

it should return `2`.

(yes I am aware that I could write a loop that just searches through all of it, but I dislike that solution as it is rather time-consuming, (to write and during runtime))

.count maybe?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
>>> list = [['foobar', 'a', 'b'], ['x', 'c'], ['y', 'd', 'e', 'foobar'], ['z', 'f']]
>>> sum(x.count('foobar') for x in list)
2
```

Answer (score 7):

First [join the lists together using `itertools`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python), then just count each occurrence using the [`Collections` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter

some_list = [['foobar', 'a', 'b'], ['x', 'c'], ['y', 'd', 'e', 'foobar'], ['z', 'f']]
totals = Counter(i for i in list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(some_list)))
print(totals["foobar"])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>> from collections import Counter
>> counted = Counter([item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist])
>> counted.get('foobar', 'not found!')
>> 2
#or if not found in your counter
>> 'not found!'
```

This uses flattening of sublists and then using the [collections](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) module and [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)
to produce the counts of words.