# (Python) Assigning a variable the count of times a specific character appears in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, counting

## Hi all,

I'm fairly new to Python as a language but have some experience with C# and Javascript, so this may be a basic question.

I'm trying to count how many times a single character appears in a multi-dimensional array from a decided start and finish point within the array, and then assign this counted value to a variable. For example:

```
array1 = [['a', 1],['a', 4],['b', 3],['c', 4]]
```

I would then want to assign variable 'x' how many times a character like 'a' appears in the array from the starting position only to the third position in the array. My attempts at this are:

```
x = array1[0:2].count('a')
x = ('a' in array1[0:2]).count
x = count('a', beg= 0, end=2(array1))
```

I understand the solution may use indexing or something similar? I'm still new to the language and am struggling a little with the syntax, so apologies if the answer is blatantly obvious or I've misinterpreted something

Any help is much appreciated :)
Thanks

Comment: You may find this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718271/python-count-for-multidimensional-arrays-list-of-lists) useful. Also, by "third position in the array", do you mean the third list within the outer list, or the third item overall (so, the 'a' in the second list)?

Comment: @thisisbenmanley I mean the third list within the outer list, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of `array1` are lists, not characters, which is why none of your attempts work. You need to test the first element of each of these nested lists, not the lists.

```
x = sum(x[0] == 'a' for x in array1[0:2])
```

Or you can extract the first elements and then use `count()`

```
x = list(x[0] for x in array1[0:2]).count('a')
```

Note also that in a slice, the selected indexes don't include the final index in the slice. `0:2` means elements `0` and `1`. So if you want the first 3 elements of the list, it should be `0:3`.

Answer (score 0):

As `array1` is array of lists.You should check occurence of `"a"` in each of the lists up to index 3 of `array1`.

As you are beginner in python below is simple code for your problem.

```
array1 = [['a', 1],['a', 4],['b', 3],['c', 4]]
count=0
for ele in array1[:3]:
    for ele1 in ele:
        if ele1=="a":
            count+=1
print(count)
```

Output:
`2`

The first for loop traverses from 0 to 2 giving out element in array.

```
['a',1]
['a',4]
['b',3]
```

The next loop takes each ele and counts the value of `"a"`.