# Count all numbers from matrix list in python

Tags: python, list, function, matrix, counting

```
def count(matrix: list, number: int):

    count([[1, 4, 0, 0, 6, 3], [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 6, 0]], 0)
```

I am trying to make function that counts all zeros or any other number from matrix list but for now its 0.

Comment: Because your input list contains only lists none of each equals 0. You need to [flatten it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists) first

Comment: So what does your code look like right now?

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? [python .count for multidimensional arrays (list of lists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718271/python-count-for-multidimensional-arrays-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
def count(matrix: list, number: int):
    return sum(l.count(number) for l in matrix)

count([[1, 4, 0, 0, 6, 3], [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 6, 0]], 0)
# 9

count([[1, 4, 0, 0, 6, 3], [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 6, 0]], 6)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
def count(matrix: list, number: int):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matrix)).count(number)
    
count([[1, 4, 0, 0, 6, 3], [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 5, 6, 0]], 0)
```

> 9