# Why PIL can't load a jpeg image?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I find the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984426/python-pil-ioerror-image-file-truncated-with-big-images/23575424#23575424) and the solution works. But I don't want the grey shade for lost/truncated bytes. I would more likely appreciate proper cause of that problem.

My attempt:

```
from PIL import Image
in_file = open("/root/1735221450770222881.jpg", "rb")    
data = in_file.read()
print len(data)

im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(data))
print type(im)

thumb_io = StringIO.StringIO()

try:
    out = im.load()
except IOError as e:
    pass
```

Traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test_image.py", line 25, in 
>      out = im.resize((3200, 3200), Image.LANCZOS)
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1557, in >resize
>
> self.load()
>    File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 232, >in load
>      "(%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
>   IOError: image file is truncated (14 bytes not processed)

N.B. This is not a generic problem. For most of my image, no error raises. Eventually, I want to resize the  image, for some it succeeds and for some a grey layer added at the bottom.

Comment: Show error stack trace

Comment: try increasing memory/buffer limit so big images can be loaded and/or load big images by chuncks, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765647/how-to-read-a-large-image-in-chunks-in-python