# Python OpenCv, only read part of image

Tags: python, opencv

I have thousands of large .png images (screenshots).  I'm using opencv to do image recognition on a small portion of each image.  I'm currently doing:

```
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    x,y,w,h = bounds
    image = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

The profiler tells me `cv2.imread` is a bottleneck.  I'm wondering if I can make the script faster by only reading the part of each image I'm interested in rather than loading the entire image and then cropping to the bounds.  I can't find an OpenCV flag for that though.  Am I missing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, there's no way to do this with OpenCV.  But I did find a solution here:  [Load just part of an image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695249/load-just-part-of-an-image-in-python/19772446#19772446)

Simply using PIL to save the cropped region of interest when generating the screenshots works.