# python matplotlib.pyplot imread

Tags: python, matplotlib, imread

I'm using `plt.imread` for reading big .tiff images.
Because of the big dimensions, I would like to select just a part of the image to be loaded.
I would like to do something like:

```
plt.imread(filename, [s1:s2, r1:r2])
```

choosing the initial and final pixel for both dimensions.

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878165/python-opencv-only-read-part-of-image.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695249/load-just-part-of-an-image-in-python

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to read the entire image, after which you can slice it before you do any processing on it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_img = plt.imread('my_img.tiff')
my_clipped_img = my_img[s1:s2,r1:r2]
```

or, in one line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
my_img = plt.imread('my_img.tiff')[s1:s2,r1:r2]
```

The latter has the benefit of not creating a full sized array, but just of the size you want.

Bear in mind that s1:s2 here should be your limits in the vertical direction, and r1:r2 in the horizontal direction.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that it would be possible to read only a portion of the file would be if it were in a columnar format *and* partitioned on disk both horizontally (rows) and vertically (columns).   *Hive*, and *Hadoop* provide such mechanisms (and *Spark* supports them). But those are for more datastores and not for individual (image) files.

So the answer from `tmdavison` is correct - and maybe this provides some  better feel for why that is.