# Lazy image manipulation in Python to process huge files

Tags: python, image, image-manipulation, large-data

I am working on a project in Python that implies manipulating images that are pretty huge (can go up to 1.5GB).

Since filtering operations are generally local, I do not need to load the entire image to detect small objects in the images for instance. Therefore, I guess one possible solution would be to load a small patch in the image, process it, consider the next patch, and so on...

However, I believe I am not the first one to be facing this problem, and some sort of lazy library has probably been developed already. Does anybody have a pointer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `libvips` is your friend.... http://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/

Comment: There is a discussion on a related subject (image chunk manipulation) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695249/load-just-part-of-an-image-in-python)