# Optimize pytorch data loader for reading small patches in full HD images

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

I'm training my neural network using PyTorch framework. The data is full HD images (1920x1080). But in each iteration, I just need to crop out a random 256x256 patch from these images. My network is relatively small (5 conv layers), and hence the bottleneck is being caused by loading the data. I've provided my current code below. Is there any way to optimize loading the data and speed up the training?

**Code**:

```
from pathlib import Path

import numpy
import skimage.io
import torch.utils.data as data

import Imath
import OpenEXR


class Ours(data.Dataset):
    """
    Loads patches of resolution 256x256. Patches are selected such that they contain atleast 1 unknown pixel
    """

    def __init__(self, data_dirpath, split_name, patch_size):
        super(Ours, self).__init__()
        self.dataroot = Path(data_dirpath) / split_name
        self.video_names = []
        for video_path in sorted(self.dataroot.iterdir()):
            for i in range(4):
                for j in range(11):
                    view_num = i * 12 + j
                    self.video_names.append((video_path.stem, view_num))
        self.patch_size = patch_size
        return

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        video_name, view_num = self.video_names[index]

        patch_start_pt = (numpy.random.randint(1080), numpy.random.randint(1920))

        frame1_path = self.dataroot / video_name / f'render/rgb/{view_num + 1:04}.png'
        frame2_path = self.dataroot / video_name / f'render/rgb/{view_num + 2:04}.png'
        depth_path = self.dataroot / video_name / f'render/depth/{view_num + 1:04}.exr'
        mask_path = self.dataroot / video_name / f'render/masks/{view_num + 1:04}.png'
        frame1 = self.get_image(frame1_path, patch_start_pt)
        frame2 = self.get_image(frame2_path, patch_start_pt)
        mask = self.get_mask(mask_path, patch_start_pt)
        depth = self.get_depth(depth_path, patch_start_pt, mask)

        data_dict = {
            'frame1': frame1,
            'frame2': frame2,
            'mask': mask,
            'depth': depth,
        }
        return data_dict

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.video_names)

    @staticmethod
    def get_mask(path: Path, patch_start_point: tuple):
        h, w = patch_start_point
        mask = skimage.io.imread(path.as_posix())[h:h + self.patch_size, w:w + self.patch_size][None]
        return mask

    def get_image(self, path: Path, patch_start_point: tuple):
        h, w = patch_start_point
        image = skimage.io.imread(path.as_posix())
        image = image[h:h + self.patch_size, w:w + self.patch_size, :3]
        image = image.astype(numpy.float32) / 255 * 2 - 1
        image_cf = numpy.moveaxis(image, [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0])
        return image_cf

    def get_depth(self, path: Path, patch_start_point: tuple, mask: numpy.ndarray):
        h, w = patch_start_point

        exrfile = OpenEXR.InputFile(path.as_posix())
        raw_bytes = exrfile.channel('B', Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT))
        depth_vector = numpy.frombuffer(raw_bytes, dtype=numpy.float32)
        height = exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].max.y + 1 - exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].min.y
        width = exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].max.x + 1 - exrfile.header()['displayWindow'].min.x
        depth = numpy.reshape(depth_vector, (height, width))

        depth = depth[h:h + self.patch_size, w:w + self.patch_size]
        depth = depth[None]
        depth = depth.astype(numpy.float32)
        depth = depth * mask
        return depth
```

Finally, I'm creating a DataLoader as follows:

```
train_data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True, num_workers=4)
```

**What I've tried so far**:

1. I've searched if it is possible to read a part of the image. Unfortunately, I didn't get any leads. Looks like python libraries read the full image.
2. I'm planning to read more patches from a single image so that I will need to read fewer images. But in PyTorch framework, the `get_item()` function has to return a single sample, not a batch. So, in each `get_item()` I can read only a patch.
3. I'm planning to circumvent this as follows: Read 4 patches in `get_item()` and return patches of shape `(4,3,256,256)` instead of `(3,256,256)`. Later when I read a batch using dataloader, I'll get a batch of shape `(BS,4,3,256,256)` instead of `(BS,3,256,256)`. I can then concatenate the data along `dim=1` to convert `(BS,4,3,256,256)` to `(BS*4,3,256,256)`. Thus I can reduce `batch_size` (`BS`) by 4 and hopefully this will speed up data loading by 4 times.

Are there any other options? I'm open to all kind of suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: did you consider slicing the patches as a preprocessing step, saving the small images and only reading the relevant patch in get_image?
if you must have the random crop augmentation you can have the patches overlap and have a size larger than 256 pixels, this might have more or less the same effect as your augmentation

Comment: an alternative solution would be to save bmps and only read the relevant parts like in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695249/load-just-part-of-an-image-in-python

Comment: Saving cropped frames won't work for me since the size will increase drastically. The alternative solution looks interesting. I'll check that. Thanks