# How can I load part of a .png file in a given range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a video game where the world will be ~30000x10000 pixels. I want the whole world to be a single .png file. Keeping the whole world loaded is computationally expensive, so I would like to load only the part of the .png file around the player. How can I load part of a .png file in a given range?

Comment: If the world isn't going to be all loaded at once, why saving it to a single file? Why not splitting it into a number (100) of smaller files, which can be easily loaded on demand (depending on character's position)?

Comment: I might end up doing that! I know that type of chunking is common. Still, I want to know if there's a way to load only part of a .png and how that solution might impact how fast my game runs.

Comment: Most libraries load images in their entirety. `vips` is able to efficiently load a subset of an image. TIFFs have the concept of strips and tiles which can make it even more efficient to extract subsets or regions.

Comment: Using `cv2` its easy... just do cv.imread()  and you can cut it up like a numpy array.  In fact it is a numpy array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load just part of an image in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695249/load-just-part-of-an-image-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19772354/9877065 --> Load just part of an image in python