# removing specific items from a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings and I want to remove specific elements in each string from it. Here is what I have so far:

```
s = [ "Four score and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth on",
      "this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated"]

result = []
for item in s:
    words = item.split()
    for item in words:
        result.append(item)

print(result,'\n')

for item in result:
    g = item.find(',.:;')
    item.replace(item[g],'')
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago,', 'our', 'fathers', 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation,', 'conceived', 'in', 'liberty', 'and', 'dedicated']
```

In this case I wanted the new list to contain all the words, but it should not include any punctuation marks except for quotes and apostrophes.

```
 ['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago', 'our', 'fathers', 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation', 'conceived', 'in', 'liberty', 'and', 'dedicated']
```

Even though am using the find function the result seems to be same. How can I correct it prints without the punctuation marks? How can I improve upon the code?

Comment: What is the exact output that you're expecting for the above list?

Comment: @CristiFati the second output that he presents is his desired output i believe. I've tested his code and both his prints output the first output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could strip all the characters that you want to get rid of after you split the string:

```
for item in s:
    words = item.split()
    for item in words:
        result.append(item.strip(",."))  # note the addition of .strip(...)
```

You can add whatever characters you want to get rid of to the String argument to `.strip()`, all in one string. The example above strips out commas and periods.

Comment: But beware of cases like "new nation,conceived", i.e. punctuation without whitespace. May or may not be a problem.

Comment: Excellent point. This was my Occam's razor approach. Regex would probably give you the most robust solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `re.split` to specify a regular expression to split on, in this case everything not a number or digit.

```
import re
result = []
for item in s:
    words = re.split("[^A-Za-z0-9]", s)
    result.extend(x for x in words if x) # Include nonempty elements
```

Comment: Testing this out, I get a bunch of repeats of my words if I use the `for` loop, but it behaves exactly the way we want if we omit the `for` loop entirely.

Comment: Also you can add a `"+"` the end of the regex (look for one or more matching characters per group) to get rid of inter-word spaces in your matched list. I still get a blank string at the end of my matched word list when I have a period at the end of my sentence though. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [ "Four score and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth on", "this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated"]

# Replace characters and split into words
result = [x.translate(None, ',.:;').split() for x in s] 

# Make a list of words instead of a list of lists of words (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/716761/1477364)
result = [inner for outer in result for inner in outer] 

print s
```

Output:

```
['Four', 'score', 'and', 'seven', 'years', 'ago', 'our', 'fathers', 'brought', 'forth', 'on', 'this', 'continent', 'a', 'new', 'nation', 'conceived', 'in', 'liberty', 'and', 'dedicated']
```

Answer (score 1):

or, you could just add a loop in

```
for item in result:
    g = item.find(',.:;')
    item.replace(item[g],'')
```

and split up `,.:;`
just add an array of punctuation like

```
punc = [',','.',':',';']
```

then iterate through it inside `for item in result:` like

```
for p in punc:
    g = item.find(p)
    item.replace(item[g],'')
```

so the full loop is

```
punc = [',','.',':',';']
for item in result:
    for p in punc:
        g = item.find(p)
        item.replace(item[g],'')
```

I've tested this, it works.