# Changing lists inside a list to strings inside a list

Tags: python, string, nested-lists

How do I return my list so that the list is composed of strings rather than lists?

**Here is my attempt:**

```
def recipe(listofingredients):
    listofingredients = listofingredients 
    newlist = []
    newlist2 = []

    for i in listofingredients:
        listofingredients = i.strip("\n")
        newlist.append(listofingredients)

    for i in newlist:
        newlist = i.split()
        newlist2.append(newlist)
    return newlist2

result = recipe(['12345\n','eggs 4\n','$0.50\n','flour 5\n','$2.00\n'])
print result
```

**And my output is this:**

```
[['12345'], ['eggs', '4'], ['$0.50'], ['flour', '5'], ['$2.00']]
```

**Desired output:**

```
['12345', 'eggs', '4', '$0.50', 'flour', '5', '$2.00']
```

I know that my issue here is appending one list to another, but I'm not sure how to use .strip() and .split() on anything other than a list.

Comment: theres a lot of wierd stuff going on in your code... but to answer your question, change `newlist2.append(newlist)` to `newlist2.extend(newlist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extend` and `split`:

```
>>> L = ['12345\n','eggs 4\n','$0.50\n','flour 5\n','$2.00\n']
>>> res = []
>>> for entry in L:
        res.extend(entry.split())
>>> res
['12345', 'eggs', '4', '$0.50', 'flour', '5', '$2.00']
```

`split` splits at white spaces per default. Strings with a new line a the end and no space inside are turned into a one-element list:

```
>>>'12345\n'.split()
['12345']
```

Strings with a space inside split into a two-element list:

```
>>> 'eggs 4\n'.split()
['eggs', '4']
```

The method `extend()` helps to build a list from other lists:

```
>>> L = []
>>> L.extend([1, 2, 3])
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
>>> L.extend([4, 5, 6])
L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: It didn't work quite right for me :(
Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Works for your example data. ;). *didn't work quite right* is a bit too vague to improve my solution. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's way of doing this. Take the advantage of [list comprehension](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) and [strip()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) method.

```
recipes = ['12345\n','eggs 4\n','$0.50\n','flour 5\n','$2.00\n']
recipes = [recipe.split() for recipe in recipes]
print sum(recipes, [])
```

Now the result will be

```
['12345', 'eggs', '4', '$0.50', 'flour', '5', '$2.00']
```

For further reading
https://stackoverflow.com/a/716482/968442
https://stackoverflow.com/a/716489/968442

Comment: Thanks! Reading over the questions you suggested were quite helpful!