# Concatenate a list of lists in a list Python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

i tried itertools,map() but i don't knoow what wrong. Ihave this:

```
[['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}', ['-', '-', '-', ... , '-', '-', '-', '-']],['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP1-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}', ['-', '-', '-', ... , '-', '-', '-', '-']],['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP12-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}', ['-', '-', '-', ... , '-', '-', '-', '-']]]
```

I want this:

```
[['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}','-', '-', '-', ... , '-', '-', '-', '-'],['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP1-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}','-', '-', '-', ... , '-', '-', '-', '-'],['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP10-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}','-', '-', '-', ... , '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

I tried

```
for i in x:
    map(i,[])
```

and this

```
import itertools
a = [["a","b"], ["c"]]
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
```

pls enlighten me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be better *Pythonic* solutions, but you can use:

```
n = []
for x in your_list:
    temp_list = [x[0]]
    [temp_list.append(y) for y in x[1]]
    n.append(temp_list)

print(n)
```

---

Outputs:

```
[['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}', '-', '-', '-', Ellipsis, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP1-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}', '-', '-', '-', Ellipsis, '-', '-', '-', '-'], ['>Fungi|A0A017STG4.1/69-603 UP12-domain-containing protein {ECO:0000313|EMBL:EYE99555.1}', '-', '-', '-', Ellipsis, '-', '-', '-', '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

simple oneliner can do:

```
[sum(x, []) for x in yourlist]
```

note sum(x, []) is rather slow, so for serious list merging use more fun and lighting fast list merging techniques discussed at

[join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

for example, simple two liner is way faster

```
import itertools
map(list, (map(itertools.chain.from_iterable, yourlist)))
```