# Joint nested list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How to convert a nested list like below?

```
d = [[['a','b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['e', 'f']]]
-> [['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f']]
```

I found a similar question. But it's a little different.
[join list of lists in python [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

### Update

Mine is not smart

```
new = []

for elm in d:
    tmp = []
    for e in elm:
         for ee in e:
              tmp.append(ee)
    new.append(tmp)

print(new)
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: show us your attempt

Comment: I added my solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, but one way is with chain

```
from itertools import chain
[list(chain(*x)) for x in d]
```

results in:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: The `range(len(...)` indirection seems unnecessary. `[list(chain(*x)) for x in d]` would be enough.

Comment: True, for some reason I gravitate to iterating over index rather than items, but changed answer as it is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

`sum(ls, [])` to flatten a list has issues, but for short lists its just too concise to not mention

```
d = [[['a','b'], ['c']], [['d'], ['e', 'f']]]

[sum(ls, []) for ls in d]

Out[14]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
```

Comment: This is also nice!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution for your question

```
new_d = []
for inner in d:
    new_d.append([item for x in inner for item in x])
```