# How to append two-dimensional python list without for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

Let's suppose that I have 3 python two-dimensional lists (`data_1`, `data_2`, `data_3`) of 10x5 dimensions. I want to make one list (`all_data`) from them with 30x5 dimensions. For now, I am doing this by applying the following:

```
data_1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ..., [46, 47, 48, 49, 50]]
data_2 = [[101, 102, 103, 104, 105], [106, 107, 108, 109, 110], ..., [146, 147, 148, 149, 150]]
data_3 = [[201, 202, 203, 204, 205], [206, 207, 208, 209, 210], ..., [246, 247, 248, 249, 250]]
all_data = []
for index, item in enumerate(data_1):
    all_data.append(item)

for index, item in enumerate(data_2):
    all_data.append(item)

for index, item in enumerate(data_3):
    all_data.append(item)
```

If I simply do something like this:

```
all_data.append(data_1)
all_data.append(data_2)
all_data.append(data_3)
```

then I get a list of 3x10x5 which is not what I want.

So can I create a 30x5 list by appending three 10x5 lists without using any for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just `extend` your list.

```
data = []
data.extend(d1)
data.extend(d2)
data.extend(d3)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this produces a 10x15 list and not a 30x5 list from the initial lists...

Comment: No, it does not (like every answer you commented on). Consider sharing your list.

Answer (score 5):

Simply write:

```py
all_data = data_1 + data_2 + data_3
```

If you want to merge all the corresponding sublists of these lists, you can write:

```py
# function that merges all sublists in single list
def flatten(l):
    return [el for subl in l for el in subl]

# zipped - is a list of tuples of corresponding items (our deep sublists) of all the lists
zipped = zip(data_1, data_3, data_3)

# merge tuples to get single list of rearranges sublists
all_data = flatten(zipped)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this produces a 10x15 list and not a 30x5 list from the initial lists...

Comment: if `data_1` and `data_2` and `data_3` contains sublists, what dimension have `data_1`? And what dimension have it's sublist?

Comment: Thank you for completing the question. I added an alternative option to my answer. But I think that you are somewhere wrong about the dimensions of the desired list. The first option should give a dimension of 30 * 5.

Comment: Thank you for your correct response again (two upvotes).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
all_data = data_1 + data_2 + data_3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but this produces a 10x15 list and not a 30x5 list from the initial lists...

Comment: @Universalis can you provide me with an example, please? Cuz what I've posted does what you've described up there - namely put the elements of the 3 lists(be they lists or not) into one list. How does a "10x5" list look like?

Comment: I think he doesn't even know how his lists look like.

Comment: @jsmolka it's very simple to run his code across any of the answers and compare the output... anyway.

Comment: Those are just one dimensional list, there is nothing two dimensional about them.

Comment: @Universalis How are those 10x5?

Comment: Check again please

Comment: @Universalis Every code on this page returns your 30x5 list for those lists.

Comment: @Universalis how did you get 10x15 lists? Did you run that very code? Give it a try in the python command line and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
data=[]
data[len(data):] = data1
data[len(data):] = data2
data[len(data):] = data3
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't mind it being lazy, you could also do

```
import itertools

all_data = itertools.chain(data1, data2, data3)
```