# Append many lists at once

Tags: python, list

Which is the most pythonic way and the fastest way (could be the same) to append many list together? For example, given the lists below:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
d = [7, 8]
```

we get one list:

```
combined = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @slackmart: simple loop and list comprehension (more pythonic than simple loop), not sure if the fastest or most pythonic though

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.5+, you can use the generic unpacking:

```
combined = [*a, *b, *c, *d]
```

or prior to Python 3.5+, you can use `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain
combined = list(chain(a, b, c, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand you 
do you mean how to merge them?
for example

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
d = [7, 8]
combined = a + b + c + d
```

so combined will be

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: While this solution is easy to read, it is less efficient because with every `+` operation a new list is created with the lists in both operands copied to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
d = [7, 8]
a.extend(b)
a.extend(c)
a.extend(d)
```

Now:

```
print(a)
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```