# How to create one single array with multiple array in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have this code to make an array that shows the index of "frq_peak" that contains each elements of "F".

```
a =[]
for i in range(len(F)):
    if i == 0:
        a.append(np.where(frq_peak[6] == F[i]))
    elif F[i] != F[i-1]:
        a.append(np.where(frq_peak[6] == F[i]))
a
```

the problem is that  "a" become a combination of multiple array but I want to have just one. what should I do?

Comment: Use `extend` instead of `append`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [join list of lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716477/join-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: I have used `extend` but `len(a)` is still not 1!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, where your array is `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`:

```py
from functools import reduce

arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

singleArray = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, arr)
```