# How flatten a list of lists one step

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of tuples

```
A= [ [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], [(7,8,9),(8,7,6),(5,4,3)],[(2,1,0),(1,3,5)] ]
```

The outer list can have any number of inner lists, the inner lists can have any number of tuples, a tuple always has 3 integers.

I want to generate all combination of tuples, one from each list:

```
[(1,2,3),(7,8,9),(2,1,0)]
[(1,2,3),(7,8,9),(1,3,5)]
[(1,2,3),(8,7,6),(2,1,0)]
...
[(4,5,6),(5,4,3),(1,3,5)]
```

A simple way to do it is to use a function similar to `itertools.poduct()`
but it must be called like this

```
itertools.product([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], [(7,8,9),(8,7,6),(5,4,3)],[(2,1,0),(1,3,5)])
```

i.e the outer list is removed. And I don't know how to do that. Is there a better way to generate all combinations of tuples?

Comment: How deep can the nested levels of lists be.  Just 2, as in your example?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+flatten, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120886/python-idiom-to-chain-flatten-an-infinite-iterable-of-finite-iterables, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python

Comment: @S Lott, related but not duplicates.  (I thought so too, initially, the "flatten" keyword is misleading I think.  Thought of editing title but didn't find a better expression; maybe "enumerate combinations"...

Comment: Maybe wrong word, but thought it was about "flatten" when I wrote the question. No, it is not homework. I got my degree '83, been working sice then. But new with python. trying to solve a quiz in a swedish newspaper lead to all my questions so far.

Comment: "Cartesian product" is maybe the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
itertools.product(*A)
```

For more details check the [python tutorial](http://www.python.org/doc/current/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Answer (score 2):

This works for your example, if there is only one level of nested lists (no lists of lists of lists):

```
itertools.product(*A)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can probably call itertools.product like so:

```
itertools.product(*A) # where A is your list of lists of tuples
```

This way it expands your list's elements into arguments for the function you are calling.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but ...

I'm new to python and come from a lisp background. This is what I came up with (check out the var names for lulz):

```
def flatten(lst):
    if lst:
        car,*cdr=lst
        if isinstance(car,(list)):
            if cdr: return flatten(car) + flatten(cdr)
            return flatten(car)
        if cdr: return [car] + flatten(cdr)
        return [car]
```

Seems to work. Test:

```
A = [ [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], [(7,8,9),(8,7,6),(5,4,3)],[(2,1,0),(1,3,5)] ]

flatten(A)
```

Result:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (8, 7, 6), (5, 4, 3), (2, 1, 0), (1, 3, 5)]
```

Note: the line `car,*cdr=lst` only works in Python 3.0

Comment: -1 The statement ``car,*cdr=lst`` isn't even legal Python. There is no direct syntax in Python to split a list in its head and tail (sorry 'bout that).

Comment: @ThomasH:  It *is* valid in Python 3.  See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/.  +1 to counteract needless downvote.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks for the pointer. I thought I was checking the Python 3 docs too, but obviously missed the `*target`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly one step, but this would do what you want if for some reason you don't want to use the itertools solution:

```
def crossprod(listoflists):
    if len(listoflists) == 1:
        return listoflists
    else:
        result = []
        remaining_product = prod(listoflists[1:])
        for outertupe in listoflists[0]:
            for innercombo in remaining_product[0]:
                newcombo = [outertupe]
                newcombo.append(innercombo)
                result.append(newcombo)
        return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def flatten(A)
    answer = []
    for i in A:
        if type(i) == list:
            ans.extend(i)
        else:
            ans.append(i)
    return ans
```

Comment: you need to fix your indentation.

Comment: Terribly sorry for indentation errors. Turns out that copying code from my local IDE does not preserve proper indentation when I paste here

Answer (score -1):

This may also be achieved using list comprehension.

```
In [62]: A = [ [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], [(7,8,9),(8,7,6),(5,4,3)],[(2,1,0),(1,3,5)] ]

In [63]: improved_list = [num for elem in A for num in elem]

In [64]: improved_list
Out[64]: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (8, 7, 6), (5, 4, 3), (2, 1, 0), (1, 3, 5)]
```