# How can I completely flatten a list (of lists (of lists) ... )

Tags: list, raku, flatten

I was wondering about how I could completely flatten lists and things that contain them. Among other things, I came up with this solution that slips things that have more than one element and puts them back, or takes things with one element after slipping it.

This is a bit different than [How do I “flatten” a list of lists in perl 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37173023/2766176), which doesn't completely flat because the task is to restructure.

But, maybe there's a better way.

```
my @a  = 'a', ('b', 'c' );
my @b  = ('d',), 'e', 'f', @a;
my @c  = 'x', $( 'y', 'z' ), 'w';

my @ab = @a, @b, @c;
say "ab: ", @ab;

my @f = @ab;

@f = gather {
    while @f {
        @f[0].elems == 1 ??
            take @f.shift.Slip
                !!
            @f.unshift( @f.shift.Slip )
        }
    }

say "f: ", @f;
```

This gives:

```
ab: [[a (b c)] [(d) e f [a (b c)]] [x (y z) w]]
f: [a b c d e f a b c x y z w]
```

Curiously, I also read some python answers:

- [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/2766176)
- [How flatten a list of lists one step](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1688712/2766176)
- [flatten list of lists of lists to a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33355299/2766176)

`itertools.chain(*sublist)` look interesting, but the answers were either recursive or limited to two levels from hard-coding. The functional languages were recursive in the source code, but I expected that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no direct built-in that completely flattens a data structure even when sub-lists are wrapped in item containers.

Some possible solutions:

#### Gather/take

You've already come up with a solution like this, but `deepmap` can take care of all the tree iteration logic to simplify it. Its callback is called once for every leaf node of the data structure, so using `take` as the callback means that `gather` will collect a flat list of the leaf values:

```perl6
sub reallyflat (+@list) { gather @list.deepmap: *.take }
```

#### Custom recursive function

You could use a subroutine like this to recursively `slip` lists into their parent:

```perl6
multi reallyflat (@list) { @list.map: { slip reallyflat $_ } }
multi reallyflat (\leaf) { leaf }
```

Another approach would be to recursively apply `<>` to sub-lists to free them of any item containers they're wrapped in, and then call `flat` on the result:

```perl6
sub reallyflat (+@list) {
    flat do for @list {
        when Iterable { reallyflat $_<> }
        default       { $_               }
    }
}
```

#### Multi-dimensional array indexing

The `postcircumfix [ ]` operator can be used with a multi-dimensional subscript to get a flat list of leaf nodes up to a certain depth, though unfortunately the "infinite depth" version is not yet implemented:

```perl6
say @ab[*;*];     # (a (b c) (d) e f [a (b c)] x (y z) w)
say @ab[*;*;*];   # (a b c d e f a (b c) x y z w)
say @ab[*;*;*;*]; # (a b c d e f a b c x y z w)
say @ab[**];      # HyperWhatever in array index not yet implemented. Sorry.
```

Still, if you know the maximum depth of your data structure this is a viable solution.

#### Avoiding containerization

The built-in `flat` function can flatten a deeply nested lists of lists just fine. The problem is just that it doesn't descend into item containers (`Scalar`s). Common sources of unintentional item containers in nested lists are:

- An `Array` (but not `List`) wraps each of its elements in a fresh item container, no matter if it had one before.

  - *How to avoid:* Use Lists of Lists instead of Arrays of Arrays, if you don't need the mutability that Array provides. Binding with `:=` can be used instead of assignment, to store a `List` in a `@` variable without turning it into an `Array`:

    ```
    my @a  := 'a', ('b', 'c' );
    my @b  := ('d',), 'e', 'f', @a;

    say flat @b;  # (d e f a b c)
    ```
- `$` variables are item containers.

  - *How to avoid:* When storing a list in a `$` variable and then inserting it as an element into another list, use `<>` to decontainerize it. The parent list's container can also be bypassed using `|` when passing it to `flat`:

    ```
    my $a = (3, 4, 5);
    my $b = (1, 2, $a<>, 6);

    say flat |$b;  # (1 2 3 4 5 6)
    ```

Comment: Any chance of adding such a `deepflat` function (or operator, I nominate `||` it it isn't already taken) to 6.d?

Comment: I kinda like using the existing built ins with no braces/parens: `say gather @ab.deepmap: *.take;`.

Comment: @raiph: That does look nicer. Updated.

Comment: @mscha [speculations](http://design.perl6.org/S09.html#Multidimensional_arrays) suggest Larry's intent is to reserve prefix:<||> to "interpolate a list into a semicolon list at the semicolon level" and that the intended solution for deepflat is a `[**]` subscript.

Comment: @mscha: Well if `@ab[**]` gets implemented, there might not be a need for another operator. `|` slips something into the outer list, it doesn't affect the inner structure of the list it's applied on - so I don't think `||` would be ideal. Also, I think one of the design docs has `||` earmarked for turning a list-of-lists into a mutlidimensional subscript, a la `@tree[||@path]`.

Comment: @raiph, smls: makes sense.

Comment: deepmap FTW. As far as "avoiding containers", sometimes you have to take what other people give you. The best solution handles it all.

Answer (score 9):

I'm unaware of a built-in way to do so, though there very well might be (and if not, there probably should be).

The best I could come up with on short notice is this:

```
gather @ab.deepmap(*.take)
```

I'm not sure how gather/take interacts with the potentially parallelized evaluation of hyper operators, so the following alternative might not be safe to use, in particular if you care about element order:

```
gather @ab>>.take
```

You can put the code into square brackets if you need an array or reify it into a list via `.list`.

Lastly, this is the first solution rewitten as a retro-style subroutine:

```
sub deepflat { gather deepmap &take, @_ }
```

Comment: Heh, I didn't see you already came up with the same `deepmap` solution while I was writing my answer... And yes, once `»` learns to parallelize itself like the design docs intended, your second solution will most likely not return elements in the correct order.

Comment: [x] removed superstitious braces (and added a `deepflat` implementation)