# If a python iterator returns iterable objects, how can I chain those objects into one big iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I'll give a simplified example here. Suppose I have an iterator in python, and each object that this iterator returns is itself iterable. I want to take all the objects returned by this iterator and chain them together into one long iterator. Is there a standard utility to make this possible?

Here is a contrived example.

```
x = iter([ xrange(0,5), xrange(5,10)])
```

`x` is an iterator that returns iterators, and I want to chain all the iterators returned by x into one big iterator. The result of such an operation in this example should be 
equivalent to xrange(0,10), and it should be lazily evaluated.

Comment: It seems that Python is a very good teaching language. The itertools method didn't start working until I figured out the "old-fashioned" way first. I guess it didn't want me to take the shortcut until I had learned the long way.

Comment: Hmm. This question is a duplicate of another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120886/python-idiom-to-chain-flatten-an-infinite-iterable-of-finite-iterables

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = iter([ xrange(0,5), xrange(5,10)])
>>> a = itertools.chain.from_iterable(x)
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If that's not available on your version (apparently, it's new in 2.6), you can just do it manually:

```
>>> x = iter([ xrange(0,5), xrange(5,10)])
>>> a = (i for subiter in x for i in subiter)
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the old-fashioned way:

```
Python 2.2.3 (#42, May 30 2003, 18:12:08) [MSC 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import generators
>>> def mychain(iterables):
...     for it in iterables:
...         for item in it:
...             yield item
...
>>> x = iter([ xrange(0,5), xrange(5,10)])
>>> a = mychain(x)
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

I'm not sure what the purpose or benefit of using `iter()` is, in this case:

```
>>> x = [xrange(0,5), xrange(5,10)]
>>> a = mychain(x)
>>> list(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: Well, I said it was a contrived example. I just used `iter()` to make x into an iterator instead of a simple list. There's not actual benefit.

Comment: I thought I already gave the old fashioned way as the second part of my answer. +1. I like archeology.

Comment: @Ryan Thompson: s/iterator/iterable/ to make your question (and the answers) more general.

Comment: @aaron sterling: I like AK47 archeology: `dos_prompt> for %v in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7) do \python2%v\python -c "yield 1"` and notice where the error message changes :-)

Comment: I'm asking specifically about iterators because the real issue is doing what I want while preserving laziness, because the thing I need to iterate over is huge and would not fit in memory. My understanding is that iterators are lazily-evaluated iterables, which is why I asked about iterators.