# Idiom for flattening a shallow nested list: how does it work?

Tags: python

I found this bit of code in a module I am working on:

```
l = opaque_function()
thingys = [x for y in l for x in y]
```

I can't read this. By experiment, I was able to determe that it is flattening a 2-level nested list, but the syntex is still opaque to me. It has obviously omitted some optional brackets.

```
>>> l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> [x for y in l for x in y]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

My eyes want to parse it as either: `[x for y in [l for x in y] ]` or `[ [x for y in l] for x in y ]`, but both of those fail due to `y` not being defined.

How should I be reading this?

(I suspect I will feel very embarassed when this is explained.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120886/python-idiom-to-chain-flatten-an-infinite-iterable-of-finite-iterables http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457215/comprehension-for-flattening-a-sequence-of-sequences

Comment: That's why I prefer to use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

Comment: Niether of those "Possible duplicates" explain the syntax.

Comment: thanks for asking this.  i've been using this idiom for a long time, and have always wondered 'why does this work?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [list displays](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) documentation:

> When a list comprehension is supplied, it consists of a single expression followed by at least one `for` clause and zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. In this case, the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached.

Thus, your expression can be rewritten as:

```
thingys = []
for y in l:
    for x in y:
        thingys.append(x)
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know that multiple `for` clauses were allowed. And here I thought I was the local python expert. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This used to really confuse me.  You should read it like a nested loop:

```
new_list = []
for y in l:
    for x in y:
        new_list.append(x)
```

becomes

```
for y in l for x in y [do] new_list.append(x)
```

becomes

```
[x for y in l for x in y]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should read this as:

```
for y in l:
    for x in y:
        yield x
```

That's the generator version, but all comprehensions have the same basic syntax: while the `x` is put up front, the rest of the expression is still read left-to-right. I was confused by this at first too, expecting it to be the other way around, but it makes sense once you add filtering expressions:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,"foo","bar"], [2,3]]
>>> [x for y in l
...    if len(y) < 4
...    for x in y
...    if isinstance(x, int)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now imagine having to write this entire thing backwards:

```
[x if isinstance(x, int)
   for x in y
   if len(y) < 4
   for y in l]
```

That would be confusing even to veteran Prolog programmers, not to mention the people maintaining Python parsers :)

The current syntax also matches that in [Haskell](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonVsHaskell), which inspired list comprehensions in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
lis=[x for y in l for x in y] is Equivalent to:


lis=[]
for y in l:
   for x in y:
      lis.append(x)
```