# Python - are there other ways to apply a function and filter in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

this has been irking me for years.

given I have a list of words :

```
words = [ 'one', 'two', 'three', '', ' four', 'five ', 'six', \
         'seven', 'eight ', ' nine', 'ten', '']
```

even though it's super lightweight, I still feel weird writing this list comprehension:

```
cleaned = [ i.strip() for i in words if i.strip() ]
```

i don't like applying strip() twice.  it just seems silly.

it's slightly/negligibly faster like this:

```
_words = [ w.strip() for w in words ]
cleaned = [ w for w in _words if w ]
```

which is also the same as

```
cleaned = [ i for i in [ w.strip() for w in words ] if i ]
```

I'm wondering if there are other ways to write this.

I was largely interested in a nested loops form of list comprehensions ( see [Idiom for flattening a shallow nested list: how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585854/idiom-for-flattening-a-shallow-nested-list-how-does-it-work) ) , but I couldn't figure anything out.

### update

I put benchmark up on github, outlining my original 3 approaches, and ones shared below.

- https://gist.github.com/jvanasco/8793879

The fastest is @Martijn Pieters `filter()`; converting the inner list to a generator expression is a negligible hit to speed, but should be better for memory management (according to python's docs ).

All the speed differences involved are , expectedly, negligible and not worth sharing.

Comment: Convert the inner list to a generator.

Comment: Regarding the update: note that the `filter/map` combination may no longer be fastest when you can no longer express the conditions directly with pre-existing methods and built-ins (here, `str.strip` and the default filter behaviour triggered by `None`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A generator expression:

```
cleaned = [i for i in (word.strip() for word in words) if i]
```

Using `filter()` and `map()`:

```
cleaned = filter(None, map(str.strip, words))
```

The latter produces a generator in Python 3; apply `list()` to it or combine `map()` with a list comprehension:

```
cleaned = [i for i in map(str.strip, words) if i]
```

Comment: great ideas.  the last example needs an ` if i`

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: indeed.

Comment: i just noticed a caveat with your 2 latter approaches :  `str.strip` fails on unicode objects; `unicode.str` fails on string objects.

Comment: @JonathanVanasco: You have a mix of the two types? Then use `lambda s: s.strip()` instead of `str.strip`.

Comment: me?  I'm always using unicode.  but this is stack overflow, so someone reading this on python 2.x might be using string , and another person on 3.x is using unicode.  just concerned about future readers.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slight variation, where I create a single valued temporary list:

```
>>> cleaned = [stripped for word in words
...            for stripped in [word.strip()]
...            if stripped]
```

More generally:

```
>>> values = [transformed for value in sequence
              for transformed in [transform(value)]
              if want(transformed)]
```

Comment: That's one of the more readable variations, thanks for sharing.  it's also the longest to execute though.

Comment: Also, are you going to accept an answer? It's been a while (c:

Comment: oh, thought i did.  i updated the benchmarking gist  with your example  (https://gist.github.com/jvanasco/8793879).  it runs 1.6x longer than the fastest.  FWIW, i decided i liked `cleaned = [ i for i in [ w.strip() for w in words ] if i ]` in terms of readability vs execution tradeoffs.