# How to check if list contains any item from list in python

Tags: python

i am trying to check and print if following list contains specific string or substring using Python,

This is my input

```
[
  [
    "SessionTimeOut: Request reach to it's max time. {'VwasKXznXVVzYU6iAAAB': None} were registered but ['192.168.2.2', '192.168.2.3'] were expected."
  ],
  [
    "CommonException: element with 'id' was not found"
  ],
  [
    "JenkisException: Element missing because service was down"
  ]
]
```

Now i want to get the output string if it contains

> "SessionTimeOut: Request reach to it's max time.

I am able to check it this way

```
print('SessionTimeOut: Request reach to it's max time.' in str(response['data']))
```

It returns `True` but i also want that complete string
I am able to print that as `response['data'][0][0]` this is not a good idea.

I want to printout the complete string dynamically which contains that text, How can i achieve this.
Thank you.

Comment: So each sublist contains single string only?

Comment: The most obvious answer would be two nested `for` loops, but I'm quite sure there is a more "pythonic" way to do that.

Comment: It could become easier if you flatten the list first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120886/python-idiom-to-chain-flatten-an-infinite-iterable-of-finite-iterables

Comment: @DonnyFlaw Yes only one.

Comment: simply use `for`-loop.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

data = [
    [
        "SessionTimeOut: Request reach to it's max time. {'VwasKXznXVVzYU6iAAAB': None} were registered but ['192.168.2.2', '192.168.2.3'] were expected."
    ],
    [
        "CommonException: element with 'id' was not found"
    ],
    [
        "JenkisException: Element missing because service was down"
    ]
]

string_to_search = "SessionTimeOut: Request reach to it's max time."
print(any(string_to_search in obj for obj in chain(*data)))
```

If you want to return that specific string:

```
print([obj for obj in chain(*data) if string_to_search in obj][0])
```

**Ouptut:**

```
True
```

Comment: Yes this is returning true, May be my question was not clear i want to print that specific string which contains string to search text.
I am already getting true or false using this `'print(''SessionTimeOut: Request reach to it's max time.'' in str(response['data']))` but i want to print out that specific string which contains this.

Comment: @Zain I've updated the answer, can you check?

Comment: Yes that's working fine,Thank you. I just want to know that can't i do with the approach i used in my question?

Comment: @Zain, at least you need to iterate over all lists in data and check string occurrence.

Comment: Here we again giving the index `[0]` which is not will work if the index is different.

Comment: The solution i wrote in my question is also giving me the results if i give index, So looking for something dynamic. @funnydman

Comment: @Zain what do you mean by more dynamic?